# What happens to existing request when base url is changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

My current project has same set of services[asp.net web api]  running from two different place with different base url.  Current requirement demands that I  choose one of them depending on current setting. This setting  is read from Redis cache.

Lets say I switch to different service called 'B' from 'A' in my client. What happens to existing requests of Service A? Do they come back to client? If yes then what is ideal way to deal with such request?

Comment: This really depends on how your code is written...

Comment: I am not sure I understand this question. Each time you call a service you should get a response back from that service. It's not possible to change while the request is in flight, although you could start sending requests to service B while the response from A is still pending. Either way, the responses always match 1:1 with the requests that you sent.

Comment: @John: so the response come back to client from service A. Then what to do with those response? what should be the best strategy to deal with them ? Should they be discarded and send user an error ?I am just asking about good practices here in this situation.

Comment: Unless you are doing something extremely strange, the line of code that issues the request also blocks and waits for the response. So I don't understand what you're getting at. These questions are bizarre, Gautam. Maybe if you posted some example code I'd understand better.